# Does the reflection method always start from half-line problems?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm confused about whether my lecture notes have a typo or whether there's something that I cannot see.

It starts with the problem

$$
\begin{cases} 
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0, & \mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty) \\ 
u(x,0)=g(x), &  \mathbb{R} \times \{  t=0 \} \\
u_t(x,0)=h(x), & \mathbb{R} \times \{  t=0 \} \\
u(0,t)=0, & \{ x=0 \} \times (0, \infty)
\end{cases}
$$

and then continues with the reflection method. The notes even read:

> Let us continue the functions in the whole of $\mathbb{R}$

Isn't this problem defined for the full line? Since the first line reads:

$$\mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty)$$

Or perhaps there's a typo and the coordinates have got flipped here?

Since if one then goes on by defining

$$
\begin{cases} 
u(x,t) & x \geq 0, t \geq 0 \\
-u(-x,t), & x < 0, t \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

then I would read that this deals with a different $u$ than what's defined.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that it would seem to be a typo in your notes. The PDE should only be defined on the half line $x \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$ if you are to use the method of images.